# Request mapping does not choose correct controller method in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller where I want to have two methods: One serve all items, and the other methods serves a subset.

Request mapping for serving everything:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Request mapping for serving only partial:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"page, limit"})
```

Now, even though the user writes `/items?page=0&limit=45` the first methods is invoked. Is it possible to fix this? I would have thought that specifying further requirements on the second request mapping would be enough and that Spring MVC would choose the mapping which fullfills the requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't `params` be defined with multiple `String` parameter names as separate array entries? E.g.:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"page", "limit"})
```

Comment: Thanks, nice spotted.

Comment: Sorry, clarified my answer. I mean `{"page", "limit"}` vs `{"page, limit"}`.

Comment: No problem. I just thought you have written what I had in my original post again, but then I saw the difference and that works.